# TypeError: unsupported operand type for 'str', cast variables with nan.inf, nan.NaN, float64 evidence, but 'str' type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, casting

**Problem Defined, Data Casting**

Tying simple cast, conversion to change variable with nan.inf and nan.NaN into a safe numeric .astype("float64") to handle integers and real number fractions.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Perform read, then cast to .astype("float64"), then perform mix-max, the errors on 'train_data = (train_data - train_data.min()) / (train_data.max() - train_data.min())' in computation, since 'Age' is a float, see df.info(), what is the problem with the 'str' appears to be the unsupported operant problem variable when the 'Age' is 'float64'?

**Error Received**

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

**CODE**

```
train_data = pd.read_csv("../data/titanic/train.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("../data/titanic/test.csv")

train_data['Age'].astype(np.str).astype("float64")
test_data['Age'].astype(np.str).astype("float64")

train_data["Age"] = train_data["Age"]
test_data["Age"] = test_data["Age"]
train_age = train_data["Age"]
test_age = test_data["Age"]
train_data = (train_data - train_data.min()) / (train_data.max() - train_data.min())
test_data = (test_data - test_data.min()) / (test_data.max() - test_data.min())
train_data["Age"] = train_age
test_data["Age"] = test_age

train_data.info()
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   PassengerId  891 non-null    int64  
 1   Survived     891 non-null    int64  
     ...
 4   Age          714 non-null    float64
```

**DATA**

```
0      22.0
1      38.0
2      26.0
3      35.0
4      35.0
       ... 
886    27.0
887    19.0
888     NaN
889    26.0
890    32.0
Name: Age, Length: 891, dtype: float64
```

**FULL ERROR LOG**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py:163, in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    162 try:
--> 163     result = func(left, right)
    164 except TypeError:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py:239, in evaluate(op, a, b, use_numexpr)
    237     if use_numexpr:
    238         # error: "None" not callable
--> 239         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
    240 return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py:128, in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    127 if result is None:
--> 128     result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    130 return result

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py:69, in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     68     _store_test_result(False)
---> 69 return op(a, b)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[119], line 6
      4 train_age = train_data["Age"]
      5 test_age = test_data["Age"]
----> 6 train_data = (train_data - train_data.min()) / (train_data.max() - train_data.min())
      7 test_data = (test_data - test_data.min()) / (test_data.max() - test_data.min())
      8 train_data["Age"] = train_age

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py:70, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
     66             return NotImplemented
     68 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 70 return method(self, other)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py:108, in OpsMixin.__sub__(self, other)
    106 @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__sub__")
    107 def __sub__(self, other):
--> 108     return self._arith_method(other, operator.sub)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:6955, in DataFrame._arith_method(self, other, op)
   6951 other = ops.maybe_prepare_scalar_for_op(other, (self.shape[axis],))
   6953 self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=True, level=None)
-> 6955 new_data = self._dispatch_frame_op(other, op, axis=axis)
   6956 return self._construct_result(new_data)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:6994, in DataFrame._dispatch_frame_op(self, right, func, axis)
   6988     # TODO: The previous assertion `assert right._indexed_same(self)`
   6989     #  fails in cases with empty columns reached via
   6990     #  _frame_arith_method_with_reindex
   6991 
   6992     # TODO operate_blockwise expects a manager of the same type
   6993     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 6994         bm = self._mgr.operate_blockwise(
   6995             # error: Argument 1 to "operate_blockwise" of "ArrayManager" has
   6996             # incompatible type "Union[ArrayManager, BlockManager]"; expected
   6997             # "ArrayManager"
   6998             # error: Argument 1 to "operate_blockwise" of "BlockManager" has
   6999             # incompatible type "Union[ArrayManager, BlockManager]"; expected
   7000             # "BlockManager"
   7001             right._mgr,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   7002             array_op,
   7003         )
   7004     return self._constructor(bm)
   7006 elif isinstance(right, Series) and axis == 1:
   7007     # axis=1 means we want to operate row-by-row

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:1419, in BlockManager.operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)
   1415 def operate_blockwise(self, other: BlockManager, array_op) -> BlockManager:
   1416     """
   1417     Apply array_op blockwise with another (aligned) BlockManager.
   1418     """
-> 1419     return operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/ops.py:63, in operate_blockwise(left, right, array_op)
     61 res_blks: list[Block] = []
     62 for lvals, rvals, locs, left_ea, right_ea, rblk in _iter_block_pairs(left, right):
---> 63     res_values = array_op(lvals, rvals)
     64     if left_ea and not right_ea and hasattr(res_values, "reshape"):
     65         res_values = res_values.reshape(1, -1)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py:222, in arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
    217 else:
    218     # TODO we should handle EAs consistently and move this check before the if/else
    219     # (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41165)
    220     _bool_arith_check(op, left, right)
--> 222     res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op)
    224 return res_values

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py:170, in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    164 except TypeError:
    165     if not is_cmp and (is_object_dtype(left.dtype) or is_object_dtype(right)):
    166         # For object dtype, fallback to a masked operation (only operating
    167         #  on the non-missing values)
    168         # Don't do this for comparisons, as that will handle complex numbers
    169         #  incorrectly, see GH#32047
--> 170         result = _masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
    171     else:
    172         raise

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py:108, in _masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
    106     # See GH#5284, GH#5035, GH#19448 for historical reference
    107     if mask.any():
--> 108         result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
    110 else:
    111     if not is_scalar(y):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

My oversight on the min-max, duh, doing min-max on one variable, e.g., 'Age' so, forgot to apply the variable assignment for the computation.

```
train_age = train_data["Age"]
test_age = test_data["Age"]

train_data = (train_age - train_age.min()) / (train_age.max() - train_age.min())
test_data = (test_age - test_age.min()) / (test_age.max() - test_age.min())
```